# parse error apk android (syntax error, parsing error)

Tags: android, sdk, syntax-error, android-manifest, apk

Please help, I am suffering a second day. 
The manifesto is written:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Collect the file apk to install it on lg optimus one (2.2) and nexus 4
nexus 4 on works 
lg optimus one to write error

What's the problem? 
thank you

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.prog"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="my.prog.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

log error:

```
87-102/system_process W/PackageParser﹕ /data/app/vmdl35341.tmp (at Binary XML file line #3): Requires newer sdk version #9 (current version is #8)
```

Comment: Please provide complete manifest.

Comment: added the file contents in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved, it may be helpful: 
file build.gradle

```
defaultConfig { 
    minSdkVersion 7 
    targetSdkVersion 18 
}
```

need to change the minSdkVersion

p.s.if it did not help change the manifest